# Multiple combo box rule set component

Tags: angular, typescript, rule-engine

To simplify I have these values in a ruleset for combo boy:

```
A | B
1 | 1
1 | 2
2 | 2
2 | 3
```

Columns A and B represent values that can appear in a combo box. So when someone selects first combo box as value 1, the second combo box will only allow values 1 and 2 to be selected.
If the second combo box is selected as value 2, first combo box will only have value 2 for selection.
I say simplified because I need four combo-boxes set up with a dynamic ruleset.

Is there something in angular that can handle this kind of ruleset (a component, code, or pattern)?

Comment: Can this help you? [My answer to what I think is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66210954/3456021)

Comment: @Askirkela Maybe, this post only mentions one way switching, but I would need two way, or to be exact four way switching since there are four combo boxed.

Comment: The use of a `ngSwitchCase` allow that, unless your comboboxes `cb1`, `cb2`, `cb3` and `cb4` all depend on the previous ones, then it's a bit more complicated indeed. Can you add an example with your 4 comboboxes in your question?

Comment: I just added an example, but I have no idea how would I add the switchCase into that https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tmedmd?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did a functional example of how I did it without any of the components. For anyone needing something like this, you can check the code here:

https://angular-ivy-tmedmd.stackblitz.io